# Share same bunch of functions in different Python projects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several microservices (12 more or less) that need to share a bunch of functions that does not change too often.

I thought to incorporate those functions in a single library, but then I'd need to upgrade the reference in every service and it'd be annoying.

What would be the best solution for that? Only thing that I have in mind is to place these functions in a single file and directly import them by hard-coding the path in every service.

Comment: The cleanest way is to create a [python package](https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_py.html)

Comment: Yes, but as I wrote, then I would need to update the reference in every repository if I need to change the package.

Comment: If you have it in a (private)  repository and point to the `latest` version of the package it's just a simple `pip --upgrade`. As you should keep packages you depend on anyway up to date, this is not much extra effort. There are also [bunch of package managers](https://chadsmith.dev/python-packaging/) out there to help you with this.

Comment: Hardcoding the path of a python script to load is britle, and breaks portability.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.